# Eloquent: attach relative records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

2 models: FMType and Profile.
FMPType has many Profile records (one-to-many relation).

```
class FMPType extends Model
{
    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Profile::class, 'fmptype_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    public function fmptype() {
        return $this->belongsTo(FMPType::class);
    }
}
```

I need to copy some FMPType to another, including relative Profiles:

```
public function copy(Request $request, int $fmptype)
{
    $source = FMPType::findOrFail($fmptype);

    // Double type
    $target = $source->replicate();
    $target->name = $source->name . ' (Copy)';
    $target->save();

    // Double profiles
    foreach ($source->profiles as $profile) {
        $targetProfile = $profile->replicate();

        // Associate new Profile with new FMPType
        // Attempt 1:  add - nothing happened, works silent, link remains as in source
        $target->profiles->add($targetProfile);
        // Attempt 2: associate - error, no such method
        $target->profiles()->associate($targetProfile);

        $targetProfile->save();
    }

    return somewhere;
}
```

Here I can't associate child Profiles with parent FMPType using Eloquent methods.
The only direct assignment works: `$targetProfile->fmptype_id = $target->id`, but guess it's wrong way form Eloquent point of view.

How to do such association as it should be?

**UPDATE - How it works:**

```
public function copy(Request $request, int $fmptype)
{
    $source = FMPType::findOrFail($fmptype);

    // Double type
    $target = $source->replicate();
    $target->name = $source->name . ' (Copy)';
    $target->save();

    // Double profiles
    foreach ($source->profiles as $profile) {
        $targetProfile = $profile->replicate();

        // Associate new Profile with new FMPType
        // Save both relation and $targetProfile
        $target->profiles()->save($targetProfile);
        // This save() is not required anymore
        // $targetProfile->save();
    }

    return somewhere;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasMany` relation does not have associate, you should use `save()`. From what i can read from your code replicate is unnecessary. I guess you just want to save profiles on your `$target`.

```
foreach ($source->profiles as $profile) {
    $target->profiles()->save($targetProfile);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - this save() method save both $targetProfile and relation, so $targetProfile->save() is unnecessary